# Showing $\lim_{\nu\to\infty}\ln(\coth(\frac\nu2))\to2e^{-\nu}$ and $ \lim_{\nu\to0}\ln(\coth(\frac\nu2))\to-\ln(\frac\nu2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, control-theory, hyperbolic-functions

I am struggling to derive a couple limits I have come across in a paper I am reading.  Both involve the natural log of the hyperbolic cotangent.  The paper seems to be saying the two terms trend the same, or are equivalent, as nu gets large, or small.

$$ \lim_{\nu \rightarrow \infty }\ln\left(\coth\left(\frac{\nu }{2}\right)\right)\rightarrow 2e^{-\nu} $$

$$ \lim_{\nu \rightarrow 0}\ln\left(\coth\left(\frac{\nu }{2}\right)\right)\rightarrow -\ln\left(\frac{\nu }{2}\right) $$

I should mention these are not explicitly stated as limit formulas in the paper.  They are evaluating a boundary term after integrating by parts.  The final expression is obviously convenient for their purposes.

This is the paper for anyone wishing more context.  See top, right of page 2.

["Kramers-Kronig, Bode, and the meaning of zero" (arXiv link)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0071) by John Bechhoefer

Thanks

Comment: Use `\ln` and `\coth` for $\ln$ and $\coth$, and `\left(...\right)` for correct sized parentheses around fractions.

Comment: @Gary, I meant to have arrows rather than equal signs. 

They're trying to say the two expressions are equivalent, or trend the same, as nu becomes large or small.

Comment: @Blue Not sure the edit on the title is the best.  Please note the change in my OP

Comment: @EthanT: Whoops! Sorry. I've fixed my egregious mistake. (Of course, you're always free to re-edit someone's changes on your own.) ... My intention was just to replace the original title to give a better sense of what exactly the question was about, to aid, for instance, in later site searches. (There could be dozens of "Limits involving hyperbolic cotangent" questions.) If feasible, and provided that formatting doesn't get out of hand, a title tends to be better when *showing* a problem than when *describing* it. ... Cheers!

Comment: No worries, I figured that was the original intention ;-)  Didn't realize I could do the edits myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These results are called asymptotics, so I will use some notation that is normal for that kind of analysis. For the first one, we know that $\coth x \to 1$ when $x>>1$ so rewrite the log expression as

$$\log\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}+e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}\right) = \log\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}+2e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}\right) = \log\left(1+\frac{2e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}\right)$$

Since $\nu$ is very large, in the denominator we have $e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}} \approx e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}$. Continuing on we get

$$\log\left(1+\frac{2e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}{e^{\frac{\nu}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\nu}{2}}}\right) \approx \log\left(1+2e^{-\nu}\right) = 2e^{-\nu}+O\left(e^{-2\nu}\right)$$

by Taylor series. The $O$ means the largest extra term that differentiates the true values of the two expressions is only as big as $e^{-2\nu}$ times a constant.

For the second one, use small angle approximation

$$\log \coth\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right) = -\log \tanh\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right) \approx -\log \frac{\nu}{2}$$

since $\tanh x \approx x$ for $x<<1$

Comment: This answers my question perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, use
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} x\coth x = 1.
$$
For the first one, use
$$
\coth x = \frac{{\cosh x}}{{\sinh x}} = \frac{{1 + e^{ - 2x} }}{{1 - e^{ - 2x} }} = (1 + e^{ - 2x} )(1 + e^{ - 2x}  +\! \mathcal{O}(e^{ - 4x} )) = 1 + 2e^{ - 2x}  +\!\mathcal{ O}(e^{ - 4x} )
$$
as $x\to+\infty$ and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\log (1 + x)}}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For the first limit, rewrite the argument of the log as
$$ \coth(\frac{\nu }{2})=\frac{1+\mathrm e ^{-\nu}}{1-\mathrm e ^{-\nu}},$$
and use that near $u=0$, one has
$$\ln(1+u)=u+o(u),\qquad \ln(1-u)=-u+o(u).$$

For the second limit, add the expansion at order $1$ of $\;\mathrm e^{-\nu}=1-\nu+o(\nu)$.